# JAVA Reading web embedded PDF

Tags: java, pdf, web-scraping

I need to a way you to read some lines of web embedded pdf (like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_tutorial.pdf).

I was using the way I used for scraping normal html pages, but it seems it doesn't work for pdf web pages. Instead of having what is displayed on the pdf page I get encoded characters (the ones I can get by downloading the pdf and opening it with notepad)

I need to scrape html code from that web embedded pdf, can anybody help me?

EDIT:
now I'm trying to scrape with (str is the url)

```
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(str);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        }
        
        String html = "";
        try {
            html = IOUtils.toString(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return html;
```

and instead of having the html code i get things like:

```
%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-US) /StructTreeRoot 134 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 32/Kids[ 3 0 R 14 0 R 30 0 R 46 0 R 48 0 R 55 0 R 57 0 R 59 0 R 61 0 R 63 0 R 65 0 R 67 0 R 76 0 R 87 0 R 89 0 R 91 0 R 96 0 R 102 0 R 104 0 R 106 0 R 108 0 R 110 0 R 112 0 R 114 0 R 116 0 R 118 0 R 121 0 R 123 0 R 125 0 R 127 0 R 129 0 R 131 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R/F2 9 0 R/F3 11 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS7 7 0 R/GS8 8 0 R>>/XObject<</Image13 13 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 270>>
stream
xœµÓËJC1à} ïð/Uèœ™$“”.z±T(X=àB\ˆÔ®ªXß<©Š,ÈA³�™d>fšK‡Ír²˜‚G#Œ§¼XÃÄuåœ-JÞ!¡â°[[ss†'kÆ­5Í¹@„8 }´¦f3®$ŠŠ˜‡vÛåÍ¯6¯õi¯    L‘s·g¯Ømöá|$|5·æö§wh/¬™u5WÖ`¶œ
```

Comment: it would be great if you add more details on how you are doing the web scraping so that someone at stackoverflow can provide a meaningful answer to this question. As of now, the question seems to be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using PDFBOX https://pdfbox.apache.org/ and doing:

```
        URL url = new URL(urlOfPDF);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        PDDocument pddDocument = PDDocument.load(in);
        PDFText2HTML stripper = new PDFText2HTML();
        String text = stripper.getText(pddDocument);
        return text;
```

Comment: Don't forget to close `in` - avoid memory leaks.